# Unable to Run Celery and Celery Beat on Azure App Service Successfully

Tags: azure, django-rest-framework, azure-web-app-service, celery, celerybeat

I have my Django REST API deployed as an App Service on Azure. Within my DRF API I'm using Celery and Celery Beat to run CRON jobs overnight.

I set up an Azure Cache for Redis and I've set the broker URL to its location and have run tests. Everything works when I initialize it locally.

However, when attempting to deploy the API with a startup.sh file to run celery on server reload, it breaks. I can't reach the admin and responses no longer return. The logs show these errors:

```
Container app-api for site app-api did not start within expected time limit.
Container app-api didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start
```

I wonder if I'm setting it up wrong. In the App Service > Configuration > General Settings > Startup Command: I put startup.sh

The startup.sh file is at the root project level and contains:

```
gunicorn — bind=0.0.0.0 — timeout 600 api.wsgi & celery -A api.celery worker -l info & celery -A api.celery beat -l info
```

Even more unusual, when I remove the startup file everything works again(after manually running celery/beat commands) AND it seems to have run the periodic task even when the app service was not responding.

Any reason why this would work when initiated locally, but as soon as I use the startup file and save the setting, causing a server restart, it breaks.

I've tried many different startup file combinations, but to no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about when you run `gunicorn — bind=0.0.0.0 — timeout 600 api.wsgi && celery -A api.celery worker -l info && celery -A api.celery beat -l info` ? `&` and `&&` in shell mean two different things.

Comment: When changing to && the app crashed and gave a few errors: [here](https://prnt.sc/MesnvbchRvVd)

Comment: So you do need to run them as background processes? In that case `&;` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved by calling celery worker and beat before the start application command. I'm also using the gunicorn.

```
export LANG=C.UTF-8

celery -A <your_application> worker -l INFO --concurrency=3 --pool=eventlet & celery -A <your_application> beat -l INFO -S django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler & gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 <your_application>.wsgi
```